# Setting up an apache web server on mac os Sierra (macbook pro 13 2014)

Tags: macos, apache, web, macos-sierra

http://digitalshore.io/local-web-development-environment-apache-macos-sierra-10-12 This is the guide that i used to set up an apache server.
I did everything that was necessary but i wasn't able to run this command
$ sudo cp httpd-userdir.conf httpd-userdir.conf.bak
Answer from terminal was "Access denied"
So, I decided not to make back-up files. When i completed the proccess, i entered this in the browser
`http://localhost/~username`, where username was my actual username.
And got this response

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /~username on this server.

---

I ran `apachectl configtest`. And got this:

> Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
> AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
> AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro-Tim.local
> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message Syntax OK

What should I do?

Comment: I ran apachectl configtest. And got this    Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com] does not exist
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro-Tim.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name for MacBook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43559201/could-not-reliably-determine-the-servers-fully-qualified-domain-name-for-macboo)

Answer (score 9):

Try http://localhost/directory/ where directory is an folder in your sites folder. For some reason before Seirra this worked for me and http://localhost/~username/directory didn't (most likely the way I had it configured, don't quite remember how I did it, try them both just in case).

If both doesn't work, try the following in terminal.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/users/username.conf;
```

Add this in the file. 
Side Note: username below and anywhere else in this answer should be your machines username.

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save the changes. Then `sudo chmod 644 username.conf`

Next: `sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
Uncomment the following lines (i.e. remove the # in front of each line if it has one)

```
LoadModule authz_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule include_module libexec/apache2/mod_include.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

Then `sudo nano /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf` and uncomment the line `Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf`
Save and restart apache. `sudo apachectl restart`
http://localhost/~username/ should then be accessible. I just went through these steps and it worked for me.

Ref: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/

Comment: This always worked for me, except that in Sierra, i now get "403 Forbidden" for files that don't exist. Also, relative links in a website on http://localhost/~me/ now suddenly link to http://localhost, and then the file can't be found!

Comment: Same thing happened to me - I got a "forbidden" error in `localhost/~username`. I hadn't uncommented the line `Include /private/etc/apache2/users/*.conf` from `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`. Didn't notice this in the answer at first glance.